# How to write a log or text file to the file system in Metro Style App

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

As the title said, I would like to write an activity log of my application into a file automatically. My application is built in Javascript/HTML5, when I am debugging I can use `console.log("this is a debug log")` and track it in console. But if I want to give my test machine to a certain test users, I want to be able to track the activity logs.

Is there any way that I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just write out a file.  Example here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597