# Metro Style  site and activity track

Tags: jquery, asp.net, microsoft-metro

I would like to save all activity of my metro style site in database. My application is use `asp.net 3.5` and `jquery`.I search and find this.[How to write a log or text file to the file system in Metro Style App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133638/how-to-write-a-log-or-text-file-to-the-file-system-in-metro-style-app).But it is not so much helpful in my situation.I want a generic type function in jquery which takes different parameters and save it in database.Is there any way that I can do that or I am in completely wrong way?

Comment: What do you mean by Metro Style site? Do you want to run your application on a Windows 8 native (distributed through the store)? Or do you only mean metro look and feel?

Comment: The article you refer to is for desktop apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a callback / post using jQuery to a server function and write to database if you want to log client side events, or log only server calls (complete pages). The first one might put your server(s) under quite a bit of a stress while the latter is a common approach.

To make your life easier with logging, you can look at logging frameworks like NLog ( http://nlog-project.org/ , looks it is not very active anymore), log4net ( http://logging.apache.org/log4net/ , last version from November 2011) or Enterprise library ( http://entlib.codeplex.com/ ). Entlib is much more then logging and has a learning curve.

**Edit:** If you want to have site statistics, you might also want to look at Google analytics, Webtrends or something similar.